# inequality with absolue value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> For every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$\dfrac{\mid x+y\mid}{1+\mid x + y \mid} \le \dfrac{\mid x \mid}{1+\mid x \mid} + \dfrac{\mid y \mid}{1+\mid y \mid}$$

Having hard time proving this statement . Please help !

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked and answered frequently. You can find more identical Q&As [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cmid%20x%2By%5Cmid%7D%7B1%2B%5Cmid%20x%20%2B%20y%20%5Cmid%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cmid%20x%20%5Cmid%7D%7B1%2B%5Cmid%20x%20%5Cmid%7D%20%2B%20%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cmid%20y%20%5Cmid%7D%7B1%2B%5Cmid%20y%20%5Cmid%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Some more: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194314,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/983043, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2277665, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386990.

Comment: Similar question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386990/proof-for-inequality-with-absolute-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac{u}{1+u}$ is increasing in $u$, and $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$.

Hence

$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leq \frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}\leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$

Comment: Please note that this has been asked and answered *very often* already.

Comment: haha apologies..

Comment: Very useful for an intermediate learner like me. Thanks